# How can I get unique random output while printing a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, random

so I want a script to give me a set of 10 simple polynomials to simplify. Lets ignore the fact that the current output is not a valid polynomial. I want to print 10 with random integers, variables and operations, but when I loop them I just get the same problem 10 times. How can I get a unique set every time?

I was having a hard time getting a unique term, but solved that problem by creating a unique term (term0, term1) etc. for each term.

```
import random

def int():
    interger = random.randint(2,10)
    return interger

def variable():
    letter  = ["x","y",""]
    variable = random.choice(letter)
    return variable

def op():
    op  = ["+","-","+"]
    operation = random.choice(op)
    return operation

term0 = op(), int(), variable()
term1 = op(), int(), variable()
term2 = op(), int(), variable()
term3 = op(), int(), variable()

for x in range(10):
    print(*term0,*term1,*term2,*term3,sep='',)
```

I would like to get a unique output for each loop, but currently I just get the same thing 10 times.

Comment: Hey guys, this is my first script I've written by myself, so if you see any inefficient coding let me know! I appreciate any constructive criticism.

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are just calling the output of the functions repeatedly. This means that the output remains the same and you are only getting the output, instead of repeatedly running the function.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to put it. I can sense theres something wrong, I just dont have the experience to see what it is yet.

Comment: Ok, good luck on your future python endeavors

Answer (score 2):

Call your random selection functions inside the loop. This way elements will be randomly selected once per iteration, instead of once before the loop:

```
for x in range(10):
    term0 = op(), int(), variable()
    term1 = op(), int(), variable()
    term2 = op(), int(), variable()
    term3 = op(), int(), variable()
    print(*term0,*term1,*term2,*term3,sep='',)
```

Comment: Man that was a quick and easy fix. Thanks for the help. Do you have any issues with the rest of the coding? I'm still not familiar with the conventions.

Comment: @rangeseeker I would probably have done it recursively to allow generating more structurally complex expressions like `(3y+(3-1))x-2xy`, but assuming you don't want to change the algorithm, I would use a list comprehension or loop instead of copy-pasting `term0...3`, and maybe write `return random.choice(["+","-","+"])` rather than splitting it over three lines. You can consider posting it to the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: Yes I really do need to learn to do more complex expressions, and ones that actually make sense. This one is very primitive, but hey its my first script on my own. Any search terms for learning more about doing this recursively?

Comment: It's technically an aspect of generative grammars in language theory, which is a fun but pretty broad topic. I was going to add a simple example to the answer, but it was pretty long and distracting so [here it is online](https://repl.it/repls/DetailedUnevenExecutables) instead. You can hit "run" several times to see what it generates.

Answer (score 0):

You did *not* generate ten polynomials.  You generated four terms for *one* polynomial, and then printed the *same data* ten times.  If you want new values, you need to call your functions inside the loop, not outside.

```
for x in range(10):
    term0 = op(), int(), variable()
    term1 = op(), int(), variable()
    term2 = op(), int(), variable()
    term3 = op(), int(), variable()

    print(*term0, *term1, *term2, *term3, sep='',)
```